# Outputting jSON in a rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

ok, rails 3 new developer here.

I want my jquery to be able to get a json object from the rails 3 application for projects. Here is my controller.

```
def yourprojects
  @projects = Projects.all(current_user)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @projects }
  end
end
```

I added the format.json line...  in jquery i have:

```
$.ajax({url: '/projects/yourprojects', dataType: 'json'});
```

So that should work i thought. Instead the server is returning: "Template is missing" "Missing template ,,,, with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :builder, :rxml, :erb], :formats=>[:html]} in view paths"

do you need a template for a jsOn return? shouldn't the rails 3 app know how to format the json?

Routes File:

```
resources :projects do
    collection do
        get 'yourprojects'  
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `Accept: application/json` header for real REST, or you can add the format to the URL for quick hackery:

```
$.ajax({url: '/projects/yourprojects.json', dataType: 'json'});
```

Comment: that is awesome - and worked! wooow thank you. I couldn't find this anywhere on Google! I like the idea of using the accept, right now I have this on the top of my JS file ($.ajaxSetup({ 'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")} })) .... Problem is some ajax request i need a .js response. others I want JSON. What's the smart way to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is not issue of Rails but rather AJAX / jQuery not sending Accept header:
Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'url_to_action', dataType: "json",
     beforeSend : function(xhr){
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
     },
     success : function(data){
       //.. do something with data
     },
     error: function(objAJAXRequest, strError, errorThrown){
       alert("ERROR: " + strError);
     }
  }
);
```

If all your AJAX requests expect JSON, then you can set header globally:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  dataType: 'json',
  'beforeSend' : function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
  } 
});
```

Other option would be adding `.json` to path or `data:{format: 'json'}` to `$.ajax` hash of options. Rails supports format path suffixes by default for `resoures` routing. Just try `rake routes` to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
:formats=>[:html]
```

That says the server is thinking that `html` is being requested.  Try adding a `.json` to your path (and possible route) and that will force the format.  TO make that would would need a route something like this:

```
map.your_projects '/projects/yourprojects.:format',
  :controller => 'projects',
  :action => 'yourprojects'
```

Somehow, someway, the `params[:format]` should be `"json"` for this request so the format handlers can do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks Squeegy, but is this for Rails 3? My config/routes looks like this to accommodate (also added to the question above): resources :projects do
    collection do
        get 'yourprojects'  
    end
end

Comment: Also, I thought Rails 3 was smart enough to determine the request type and serve the right response, ie why you can have so many different types of response types (html, js, json, xml) ?

Comment: I'm actually a bit behind and not sure how Rails 3 routes work.  But 2.x worked like I describe.  Sorry!

Comment: thanks from what I was able to find online it's totally different in Rails 3.