# Rails 3.1: Persistent "Template is missing" with JSON format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem very similar to [the one mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3798822/242826). However, none of the solutions described in the answers are working.

When trying to access my route, with or without `.json` extension, as well as with jQuery `$.ajax` and `$.getJSON` (with the correct Accept headers), I am getting the following exception:

> Missing template users/events/index, application/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml], :formats=>[:json], :locale=>[:en, :en]}.

Since I only need JSON responses for this controller, I don't have nor want any templates for this controller.

My controller is defined like so:

```
class Users::EventsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to(:json)

  def index
    # Some extra code here...
    respond_with(@data)
  end
end
```

With these routes in place (under a "user" scope):

```
resources(:events, :only => [:index, :show]) do
  collection do
    get ':year/:month', :to => 'events#index', :format => :json
  end
end
```

The problem persists when adding the `do |format|` block and explicitly making it render as JSON.

Tried this on both Rails 3.1.1 and on 3.2 and got the same issue.

It looks like a server-side issue since accessing with ".json" doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Should the controller only respond with json? If so, try `render :json => @data` instead of `respond_with`.

Comment: This was actually caused by a pretty stupid mistake on my part. See my answer. Too much JavaScript coding lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more tinkering I found out what was the actual cause of this problem.

At some point in the controller I had the following code block:

```
@array.map { |a| return a['id'] }
```

The `return` keyword was incorrectly used and caused the entire action to return ahead of time, causing the issue.

Comment: That's why it's often best to not hide code when asking. But it's good you figured it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a similar issue with a custom Devise controller when issues a password reset request via JSON (be sure to use CSRF correctly also).

#### Problematic code

```
responds_to :json => [:create, :our_custom_method1, :our_custom_method2]
```

#### Working code

```
responds_to :json
```

Not happy with the security aspect of allowing more routes to accept JSON, but we'll lock it down further later.